# Router Suggestions - Links to Configuration

Tags: networking

We are having two 10Mbit/s pipes of fiber being pulling in to the building from Time Warner. One for our internal network and the other for our external services to our customers (Website, FTP, ...). We are responsible for providing and supporting the router and although I am not new to the field I haven't had a need to purchase/config an enterprise level router in a LONG time. I would prefer to be able to have both pipes come into one router and then from that router attach it to two different networks (Local, DMZ).

So the questions I have are...

What routers would you recommend understanding we are not a large business (about 75 employees) and costs are a factor but at the same time I want to make sure we get what we really need?

Any links on some current info on router configurations? (I know my way around *nix, command line, understand networking concepts so I don't need a "tutorial" just something with some current info on on best practices or gotcha's with the router).

As always TIA!

PK

Comment: Furthermore take a look at the BGP specifications as you are probably going to use this routing protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What medium is the handover to you? Ethernet one would hope for.

Cisco 2901 routers would be suitable for this, simple 1U rackmounts capable of easily routing 10Mbit. Comes with two on-board Ethernet ports (use Cisco 2911 if you need three ports).
buy the CISCO-2901SEC bundle to get the security features for IOS included.

Comment: 2901's would be a good investment.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're not looking for a router but for a firewall. How about Cisco ASA 5505?